# Fourier Transform of wavefunction from position to momentum and plot

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I coded this wavefuntion of x on numpy and it works well.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
pi=3.14
L=1
def psi(x):
    n=1
    psi=np.abs(np.sqrt(2/L)*np.sin((n*np.pi*x)/L))**2
    return  psi
x= np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(x, psi(x))
plt.show()
```

Now I want to take Fourier transform of psi in momentum p and want to plot phi(p) vs p. But I dont understand how to take integration of psi and plot it. I tried following code but its not working.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import sympy as smp 
pi=3.14
L=1
psi=np.abs(np.sqrt(2/L)*np.sin((n*np.pi*x)/L)
def phi(p):
    n=1      
    phi=(1/(smp.sqrt(2*smp.pi)))*(smp.exp((-x*i*2*smp.pi*p)))*psi smp.integrate(phi,(x,0,L))
    return  phi
p= np.linspace(0,1,100)
plt.plot(p, phi(p))
plt.show()
```

Comment: You do not perform the integral but rather perform discretized version of the integral called as Discrete Fourier transform (DFT). An algorithm that does DFT is Fast Fourier transform (FFT). Numpy has an implementation of FFT ```numpy.fft.fft```

Comment: Is it not for frequency and time ? I need command for position and momentum. @Murali

Comment: @It is not restricted to time and frequency. In case of momentum, position, you use a 3D FFT.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in my comment, you do not perform the integral, here is an example of how to do a basic Fourier Transform using numpy

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pylab as plt

pi=np.pi

L = 1
n = 1

N = 1000 ## sampling 

x= np.linspace(0,1,N) 
psi=np.abs(np.sqrt(2/L)*np.sin((n*np.pi*x)/L) ## // Your wavefunction in real space

dx = 1/N ## sampling width
w = 1/dx ## sampling freq

psi_p = np.fft.fft(psi) ## Fourier Transform of wavefunction in momentum space

p = numpy.fft.fftfreq(x.shape[0])*w ## construct the p values. note psi(p) is periodic function with period w

plt.plot(x, psi,label='psi(x)')
plt.plot(p,psi_p.imag,label='psi(p)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```